# How do I serve two different servers to different subdomains on port 80?

Tags: apache

Currently I have two node applications on a Digital Ocean droplet, on top of an Apache install. One is on port 3000, and the other is on 3001.

I would like to route incoming requests to suba.domain.com on port 80 to the application on port 3000, and subb.domain.com on port 80 to port 3001.

[This site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992495/how-do-i-setup-virtualhosts-to-point-two-ports-on-same-ip-to-different-servernam) seemed to be what I was looking for, but it didn't work, and I also tried the solution on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898874/multiples-domains-pointing-to-differents-ports-in-apache-server), which didn't work either.

Are these not the solutions that I'm looking for? Is there something different about trying to set it up on a subdomain instead of the top level domain? I'd appreciate any advice out there - thanks in advance!

Comment: actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992495/how-do-i-setup-virtualhosts-to-point-two-ports-on-same-ip-to-different-servernam is what you will need to. You will need to Proxypass to if those were backend nodes.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks for the response - that's actually the first link that I posted, and the first solution that I tried. Where does that entry go specifically? I've been putting it into the *.conf file for my domain in the 'sites-available' folder - is that the right place?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this to work using nginx. It was way, way easier to do in nginx as opposed to trying to figure it out with apache. There was a lot more documentation for this type of stuff, so if you're trying to do something similar, to what I have listed here, consider switching to nginx.